Comparing Two-Way Fixed Effects Model using Pooled OLS and Panel Data Fixed Effects Approach
I am working with an unbalanced panel dataset that has many missing values. I want to control for both firm-specific and time-specific effects in my analysis. I am considering two approaches:
Estimating a two-way fixed effects model using pooled OLS by including both firm and year dummy variables.
Using the panel data fixed effects approach, which demeans the data within each firm and includes year dummies.
The equation for the two-way fixed effects model using pooled OLS is:
\begin{equation}
y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1it} + \dots + \beta_k x_{kit} + \gamma_2 d_{2t} + \dots + \gamma_T d_{Tt} + \delta_2 f_{2i} + \dots + \delta_N f_{Ni} + \varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation}
where:

$y_{it}$ is the dependent variable for firm $i$ at time $t$

$x_{1it}$ to $x_{kit}$ are the $k$ independent variables

$d_{2t}$ to $d_{Tt}$ are the year dummy variables ($T$ is the total number of years)

$f_{2i}$ to $f_{Ni}$ are the firm dummy variables ($N$ is the total number of firms)

$\beta_0$ to $\beta_k$, $\gamma_2$ to $\gamma_T$, and $\delta_2$ to $\delta_N$ are the coefficients to be estimated

$\varepsilon_{it}$ is the error term


My questions are:
1: Are there any significant differences in terms of estimation and interpretation between the two approaches? Like, are they essentially the same behind the scenes?
2: Given the unbalanced nature of my dataset and the presence of many missing values, which approach would be more suitable?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
